# FluentValidation for When & must?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

I am trying use FluentValidation validaton when dropdownlist value is `yes` and the field must be date. it is working when dropdownlist is `yes` checking for `date`. But
also showing validation when I select `No` still it says `Must be date`.

It should not validate anymore if dropdownlist value otherthan the `yes`. How can we do that?

```
 RuleFor(x => x.DtPublishedTimeText)
            .NotEmpty()
            .When(HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText)
            .WithMessage("Required Field")
            .Must(BeAValidDate)
            .WithMessage("Must be date");

private bool BeAValidDate(string val)
{
    DateTime date;
    return  DateTime.TryParse(val, out date);
}

private bool HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText(MeetingAbstract model)
{
    return model.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText != null && 
             model.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText.Equals("yes");
}
```

Answer (score 24):

The issue you are having is the `When` predicate only applies to one rule. You need to have conditional validation on both the `NotEmpty` AND  the `Must`.

There two ways to achieve this. Option 1 is tidier when there are only a couple of conditional rules, otherwise I'd use option 2.

```
RuleFor(x => x.DtPublishedTimeText)
    .NotEmpty()
        .When(HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText)
        .WithMessage("Required Field")
    .Must(BeAValidDate)
        .When(HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText)
        .WithMessage("Must be date");
```

Or

```
When(HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText, () => {
    RuleFor(x => x.DtPublishedTimeText)
        .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Required Field");
    RuleFor(x => x.DtPublishedTimeText)
        .Must(BeAValidDate)
            .WithMessage("Must be date");
});
```

Do note: I have no idea what `HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText` is or what it looks like. I am assuming you can use it as a predicate

---

EDIT:

I'd also look at refactoring the `HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText` method, the following is less error prone.

```
private bool HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText(MeetingAbstract model)
{
    return String.Equals(model.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText, "yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: `HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText `is the dropdown list. So I am checking the `HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText ` value is `yes` and `DtPublishedTimeText` is not empty and it should `date`

Comment: Both of my suggestions should work. I've also added a possible refactor to the `HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText` method

Answer (score 15):

You just need to change the order of your calls. Try this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.DtPublishedTimeText)
    .NotEmpty()
        .WithMessage("Required Field")
    .Must(BeAValidDate)
        .WithMessage("Must be date")
    .When(HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText);
```

The `When` applies to all previous rules. So in your code when you applied it straight after the `NotEmpty`, it applied only to the `NotEmpty` rule and not to the `Must` rule.

Full demo on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LN1sXj).

Answer (score 1):

**Tested in VERSION >= 8.4.0**
a new enum parameter is added to `When` extension method

```
public enum ApplyConditionTo
{
    //
    // Summary: (default)
    //     Applies the condition to all validators declared so far in the chain.
    AllValidators = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Applies the condition to the current validator only.
    CurrentValidator = 1
}
```

by default (AllValidators): `When` will ending by rules chain ends

(CurrentValidator): `When` will be restricted to the first previous rule