# Conditional and non-conditional in one Fluent Validation rule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I need to validate zip code, 
- it always must have a value (non-conditional)

```
// General Rule:
RuleFor( m => m.Zip ).NotEmpty()
    .WithMessage( "Zip code is required." );
```

If it's in the US, value should match regex (conditional)

```
// United States Rule:
RuleFor( m => m.Zip )
    .Matches( ZipCodeRegEx )
    .WithMessage( "Invalid Zip Code" )
    .When( m => IsUnitedStates( m.CountryCode ) );
```

My goal is to combine General Rule and United States Rule in one Rule
, I have tried:

```
// doesn't check general rule for non-us
RuleFor( m => m.Zip )
    .NotEmpty()
        .WithMessage( "Zip code is required." )
    .Matches( ZipCodeRegEx )
        .When( m => IsUnitedStates( m.CountryCode ) )
        .WithMessage( "Invalid Zip Code" );

// doesn't check general rule for non-us
RuleFor( m => m.Zip )
    .NotEmpty()
        .When( m => true )// always
        .WithMessage( "Zip code is required." )
    .Matches( ZipCodeRegEx )
        .When( m => IsUnitedStates( m.CountryCode ) )
        .WithMessage( "Invalid Zip Code" );
```

How I can write this in one rule?

Comment: What datatype is Zip? a string?
What do you have ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode set to?

Comment: Zip is string, CascadeMode is Continue.

Comment: Can you post your IsUnitedStates method?

Comment: private bool IsUnitedStates( string countryCode ) {

            return countryCode == "US";

        }

Comment: Also, the `ZipCodeRegEx` as well?

Comment: ZipCodeRegEx = @"^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible to do it in one rule. FluentValidation was not designed to support that case.

Comment: It actually is possible to do it in one rule. Check this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24026758/5656858

Comment: after testing all answers in your link and other posts, I came to conclusion that it's not possible.